# Docker Trusted Registry - Unable to satisfy available container slot

Tags: docker, docker-trusted-registry

I am trying to install the Docker Truster Registry (DTR). I am executing the following command:

```
docker run -it --rm \
docker/dtr install \
--ucp-url https://10.000.000.125 \
--ucp-node node123 \
--dtr-external-url https://10.000.000.97 \
--ucp-username admin --ucp-password admin \
--ucp-ca "$(cat ucp-ca.pem)" \
```

I am getting the following error back:

```
ERRO[0000] Make sure that there is a node in your UCP cluster where port 80 and port 443 are open. Also confirm that all UCP node have the DTR images or can obtain them from Docker Hub.
FATA[0000] Problem running container 'dtr-phase2' from image 'docker/dtr:2.0.2': Couldn't create container 'dtr-phase2' from image 'docker/dtr:2.0.2': Error response from daemon: Unable to find a node that satisfies the following conditions
[available container slots]
[node==node123 node!=node123]
```

I am able to ping the server from where I am trying to install the DTR. I do not know what that issue means. I appreciate any help

Comment: Does 80 and 443 port are really free on `node123` from `--ucp-node`?

Comment: Yes. Did a "netstat -ano | grep <port #>" on the server and nothing came back. Also tried to use telnet on them and nothing still

Comment: As a Docker Data Center customer, you can get support by filing a ticket: https://support.docker.com/hc/en-us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce the problem you have (using trial DTR license).

I assume the node, you are installing DTR on, is already joined to the UCP cluster and you can test connection from the DTR node to the TCP port 443 on a UCP controller.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-trusted-registry/install/):

`dtr-external-url, is the public IP or domain name where DTR can be reached`

So, precisely speaking, `--dtr-external-url` should be `10.000.000.97` in your case (although I agree the parameter name is a bit misleading).

It's hard to advise something without knowing any details about your UCP configuration (such as networking, etc). But considering the error message, I would advise to verify that hostname of your DTR node is indeed set to `node123` and is correctly resolved to `10.000.000.97`.

Comment: Actually no, the DTR was not installed on one of the UCP nodes. It was on it's own server outside the cluster - it just had access to the UCP nodes on the network. I didn't put it on one of the nodes because the documentation says it needs port 80 and 443 open, but the UCP would have taken those.

Comment: From: https://docs.docker.com/docker-trusted-registry/install :
`Make sure that the node you install DTR on is already joined to the UCP cluster.` Try installing DTR on a UCP node not controller.